# Laravel soft delete at User model not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

I add soft delete to User model.

Like `use SoftDeletes` and `$dates = ['deleted_at']`

When I use `User::destroy(1)` it will actually add deleted_at value in database, so I'm sure there is no setup problem about SoftDeletes.

But when I get user list and use User model to login, it won't filter deleted row.

Is there any one have the same problem? Please tell me how you solve this.

--Update--

App\User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * Added for passport - api login checking
     */
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, Searchable;

    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];
}
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Events\ErrorLog;
use App\Helpers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $fields = $request->fields ? $request->fields :
            [
                'id',
                'name',
                'email',
            ];

        $search = function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . request()->nameOrEmail . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . request()->nameOrEmail . '%');
        };

        $users = User::where($search)
            ->orderBy('id')
            ->paginate(20, $fields);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => $users,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide the code for what you're doing here: "But when I get user list and use User model to login, it won't filter deleted row." Without that code, it's going to be impossible to answer your question except by guessing.

Comment: Can you share the model code and the code used to get the user list?

Answer (score 7):

> Soft deletion filter only work for eloquent ORM

If you don't use eloquent i.e if you are using query builder or some raw sql you need to check for soft deletion manually

For example

```
$user= User::all(); //eloquent
```

is same as

```
 SELECT 
      * 
    FROM
      users
    WHERE
      deleted_at IS NULL
```

but not for

```
$users=DB::table('users') //non eloquent
```

which is just

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

In this case you need to pass some conditions

```
DB::table('users')
            ->whereNull('deleted_at');
```

> EDIT

You have used query builder which override eloquent condition, try below

```
$users = User::where($search)
             ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->orderBy('id')
            ->paginate(20, $fields);
```

Comment: I use User not DB::table('users'), do you have any ideas of this?

Comment: a little addition: `whereNull('deleted_at')` is done by default, no need to include it. if you want the deleted records also you can do ->withTrashed()

Comment: `whereNull('deleted_at')` **should** be done automatic, but in my case isn't. Might be a bug in Laravel? I'm using version 5.4.22

Comment: try this User::find($id)->delete();

Comment: **As of 2019, using Laravel 6**

The issue still exists, but only with User class.
Does anybody else have an idea why this is the case?

No exception is thrown during
``$user->delete();``

The user is just deleted in standard way.